# ¿Cómo puedo cerrar una pestaña no abierta por mí externa con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo puedo cerrar una pestaña con una dirección url que no la haya abierto yo (usando `window.open()`), con Javascript?

```js
var myWindow

function openWin() {
  myWindow = window.open("https://www.google.es");

}

function closeWin() {
  myWindow.close();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

Lamentablemente, sin no abriste tu la pestaña (no eres el propietario), no puedes cerrarla.

Es una protección del navegador.

fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: No te digo que no sea verdad, pero ¿podrías citar una fuente? A lo mejor hay matices, por ejemplo, ¿un script podría cerrar una ventana si la ventana a cerrar está ne el mismo dominio que la que trata de cerrarlo?

Comment: es como tratar de imprimir directamente desde local, sin cuadro de dialogo, si no hay algo por el medio, desde el navegador es imposible.

Comment: yo no he dicho ni que sea posible ni que no sea posible. Solo te he pedido que aportes fuentes de lo que afirmas en la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por aportar la fuente

Comment: Tienes razon, son cosas que se saben por experiencia, pero nunca me preguntado la fuente. @ordago